# File link not able to delete from linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, hyperlink, suse

I have a link as follows:

```
$ ls -l
lrw-rw-rw- 1 root root 171520 2002-10-17 16:03 fileLnk -> ??????
```

When I try to delete this file I am getting error as permission denied error
   rm: cannot remove `fileLnk': Permission denied

I could able to move the file using mv command.

I have following questions 
1) Why is the link `?????` ? 
2) Why am I not able to delete the file?

Comment: Is the disk mounted read-only? Does the file system support ACLs?

Answer (score 1):

Are you root? Try using `sudo` in front of `rm`. The question marks might be that the filename contains unprintable characters. How was the link created?

Comment: I am logged in as root. I have no idea how the link was created. I have one question here, why the link should show the file content? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the file content is not shown when you list the file, just the filename to the file the link point at. This name might contain unprintable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, is the current path of the link a mounted directory?

Comment: I have no idea because the link shows ?????, I think if the link is broken, still it should show the path right? Correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: Yes.    When the link is broken sometimes blink with a red color in Linux sometimes when the system can't control the filesystem in the correct way shows the symbols that you saw, try df -ha to know if the directory is a extern hard disk and then an fdisk -l to the device to know the filesystem, maybe CIFS, NTFS, AFP, etc, etc...